# ASP.NET Razor View Html.TextBox size/width

Tags: asp.net, razor

Is there a way to set a textbox size without using CSS (setting the columns or size attribute) ? If so, how?

```
 @Html.TextBox("redeemamt", @Model.Amount)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBox("redeemamt", @Model.Amount, new {style = "width: 100px;"})
```

or you could try with this:

```
@Html.TextBox("redeemamt", @Model.Amount, new { size = "100" })
```

Comment: @Html.TextBox("redeemamt", @Model.Amount, new {style = "width: 100px;"}) will surely works

Comment: I think he wants absolutely no kind of css styling. But yeah as stated in my answer this is possibly the only thing that will work.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're looking for Html.TextArea:

`@Html.TextArea((string)name, (string)value, (int)rows, (int)columns, (object)htmlAttributes)`

Answer (score 0):

if you have added bootstrap then you can check input properties and modify

e.g changing height

```
input[type="text"]
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
```